# How to transform a linear system?

Tags: linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, fourier-transform, periodic-functions

Consider the following system
$$
y_i=\sum_{|j-i|\leq k} x_{j}
$$
for some $k< \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$, and with indexes in the $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ ring. Essentially, $y_i$ is the sum of $x_i$ and its $2k$ "nearest neighbors". How can I transform this system to write it in terms of $x_j$?

Note that, alternatively, we may write
$$
y_i=\sum_{j=-k}^kx_{i+j}
$$
For example, with $n=5$ and $k=1$, the system becomes
$$
y_i=\sum_{|j-i|\leq 1} x_{j}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
y_1=x_1+x_5+x_2\\
y_2=x_2+x_1+x_3\\
y_3=x_3+x_2+x_4\\
y_4=x_4+x_3+x_5\\
y_5=x_5+x_4+x_1
\end{cases}
$$
which can be sketched by the periodic ring

[image]

How can I rewrite $\{x_j\}$ in terms of $\{y_i\}$?

**Comment:** Motivated by @aschepler's answer, we can actually just see this problem as
$$
\mathbf{y}=T_{n,k}\mathbf{x}
$$
where
$$
T_{n,k}=B_{2k+1}+(J_{n}-B_{2(n-k-1)+1})
$$
where $B_k$ is the symmetric banded matrix with a maximum of $k$ ones in each row of its diagonal band and $J_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of ones. We are looking for $T_{n,k}^{-1}$. Schematically,

[image]

and so, for $n=5$ and $k=1$,

[image]

However, it is not always possible to compute $T_{n,k}^{-1}$. For $n=6$ and $k=1$, $T_{6,1}$ is singular:

[image]

It could be interesting to stipulate the conditions on $n$ and $k$ such that $T_{n,k}$ is non-singular. Also, can we hope for an expression for $T_{n,k}^{-1}$ in terms of banded matrices?

Answer (score 2):

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the linear transformation from vector $x$ to vector $y$.

If $2k+1$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $T$ is non-singular. But if $d>1$ is a divisor of both $n$ and $2k+1$, then for every $r \in \{0, 1, \ldots, d-1\}$,

$$ x_i = \begin{cases} 1 & i \equiv r \pmod{d} \\ 0 & i \not \equiv r \pmod{d} \end{cases} $$

is a vector with $y = Tx$ giving the same vector $y = \frac{2k+1}{d} \mathbf{1}_n$, so $T$ is not injective.

Assuming then that $2k+1$ and $n$ are relatively prime, there is a unique number $\ell \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ so that $(2k+1) \ell \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. Let $m$ be the positive integer $m=\frac{(2k+1)\ell-1}{n}$.

The $y_i$ are related to $x_i$ by a circular discrete convolution with a rectangular filter:

$$ r_i = \begin{cases} 1 & [i] \in \{[-k], [-k+1], \ldots, [k-1], [k]\} \\
0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

$$ y = r \ast x $$

where $[c]$ denotes the equivalence class $c + n\mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Intuitively, we can imagine shifting the vector $r$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ by $2k+1$ positions at a time to get a sequence with $1$ repeated $t(2k+1)$ times. This is another convolution, by a vector with $t$ elements of value $1$, each pair separated by $2k$ elements with value $0$. If we do the same in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, the sequence wraps around and overlaps itself. But if $t=\ell$, the first $1$ in the sequence and the last $1$ coincide, and the sum in that position is exactly one more than all the others.

Working this idea out, let $s$ be the sequence

$$ s_i = \begin{cases} 1 & [i] \in \{[k], [3k+1], [5k+2], \ldots, [k+(\ell-1)(2k+1)]\} \\ 0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Convoluting $s \ast r$ gives, for $0 \leq a < n$,

$$ \begin{align*}
(s \ast r)_a &= \big|\big\{(i,j) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} : -k \leq i \leq k, 0 \leq j < \ell, i+k+j(2k+1) \equiv a \pmod{n} \big\}\big| \\
(s \ast r)_a &= \big|\big\{q \in \mathbb{Z} : 0 \leq q < \ell(2k+1), q \equiv a \pmod{n} \big\}\big| \\
(s \ast r)_a &= \left\lceil \frac{\ell(2k+1)-a}{n} \right\rceil =
\begin{cases} m+1 & a=0 \\ m & a \neq 0 \end{cases}
\end{align*} $$

Then

$$ s \ast r \ast x = x + m (\mathbf{1}_n \ast x) = x + m \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_i $$

The sum of $x$ and the sum of $y$ are related by

$$ \mathbf{1}_n \ast y = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} y_j = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sum_{i=-k}^k x_{i+j} = \sum_{i=-k}^k \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x_{i+j} = (2k+1) \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x_j = (2k+1)(\mathbf{1}_n \ast x) $$

So finally,

$$ s \ast y = s \ast r \ast x = x + \frac{m}{2k+1} \mathbf{1}_n \ast y $$

$$ x = \left(s - \frac{m}{2k+1} \mathbf{1}_n \right) \ast y $$

For the example $n=5, k=1$, we have $2k+1=3$, $\ell=2$, $m=1$, $r = (1,1,0,0,1)$, $s = (0,1,0,0,1)$, and

$$ s - \frac{m}{2k+1} \mathbf{1}_n = (0,1,0,0,1) - \frac{1}{3} \mathbf{1}_n = \frac{1}{3} (-1, 2, -1, -1, 2) $$

That is, if $\sigma_y = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} y_i$,

$$ \begin{align*}
x_1 &= y_5 + y_2 - \frac{\sigma_y}{3} \\
x_2 &= y_1 + y_3 - \frac{\sigma_y}{3} \\
x_3 &= y_2 + y_4 - \frac{\sigma_y}{3} \\
x_4 &= y_3 + y_5 - \frac{\sigma_y}{3} \\
x_5 &= y_4 + y_1 - \frac{\sigma_y}{3}
\end{align*} $$

or the matrix form of $T^{-1}$ is

$$ x = \frac{1}{3} \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
-1 &  2 & -1 & -1 &  2 \\
 2 & -1 &  2 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 &  2 & -1 &  2 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  2 \\
 2 & -1 & -1 &  2 & -1
\end{array}\right) y $$

Comment: Interesting approach. Essentially we are looking for the inverse of a sum of banded matrices. Please see the edit to my question and let me know whether a simpler expression for $T^{-1}$ might be possible. Thanks!

Comment: $T_{n,k}$ is non-singular if and only if $\gcd(2k+1,n)=1$. It's easier to represent convolution with $s$ and therefore $T^{-1}$ in terms of single diagonals at positions from $s$, but of course that can be converted to differences of bands if you want. Also, notice the matrices for $T$ and $T^{-1}$ use "wrapped" diagonals at indices $(i,j)$ where $i-j \equiv c \pmod{n}$ for some $c$. Your $J_n - B_{2(n-k-1)+1}$ is the pieces of $B_{2k+1}$ which would wrap around the edges in this manner. In the same way, a single wrapped diagonal is the sum of diagonals $c+1$ and $n-c-1$.